# Why autowire fields via autowireCapableBeanFactory without delay?

Tags: java, spring, autowired, servlet-3.0, applicationcontext

Consider a code:

```
public class MyClass {
    @Autowired
    private SomeInterface variable;

    public void init(ServletContext servletContext) {
        WebApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext); //debug point here
        context.context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().initializeBean(this, getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
}
```

When I stay at debug autowiring performs normal, but when I put debug point away I got NPE at `variable`. It seems that
Spring performs autowiring asynchronously. Is there  way to ensure that after all field are initialized?

**Note**

Yes calling `initializeBean(this, getClass().getSimpleName())` this is not a best practise of spring usage, but I have no other
way because class instantiated in other library which do not used Spring.

Comment: You should be using `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);` rather than `initializeBean`.

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned in comments it is better to use `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport` instead of `AutowireCapableBeanFactory`.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport;

@Configurable
public class MyClass {
    @Autowired
    private SomeInterface variable;

    public void init(ServletContext servletContext) {
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
    }
}
```

Not forget about `@Configurable` and `<context:spring-configured/>`. Full example is [here](http://www.javavillage.in/spring-ioc-on-servlets.php)

Comment: You shouldn't need the `@Configurable`.

Comment: It isn't necessary for `processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext` to work. Unless you need it for something else...